# footer-html not loading JavaScript in Laravel-Snappy

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-snappy

I used Laravel-Snappy to generate Pdf with large data.
I want to add page count and many more things in 'footer.php'.
I used below code from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head><script>
  function subst() {
      var vars = {};
      var query_strings_from_url = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
      for (var query_string in query_strings_from_url) {
          if (query_strings_from_url.hasOwnProperty(query_string)) {
              var temp_var = query_strings_from_url[query_string].split('=', 2);
              vars[temp_var[0]] = decodeURI(temp_var[1]);
          }
      }
      var css_selector_classes = ['page', 'frompage', 'topage', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'date', 'isodate', 'time', 'title', 'doctitle', 'sitepage', 'sitepages'];
      for (var css_class in css_selector_classes) {
          if (css_selector_classes.hasOwnProperty(css_class)) {
              var element = document.getElementsByClassName(css_selector_classes[css_class]);
              for (var j = 0; j < element.length; ++j) {
                  element[j].textContent = vars[css_selector_classes[css_class]];
              }
          }
      }
  }
  </script></head><body style="border:0; margin: 0;" onload="subst()">
  <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="section"></td>
      <td style="text-align:right">
        Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body></html>
```

**I got this below error --**

The exit status code '-1073741819' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [==============================> ] 50% [============================================================] 100% Counting pages (2/6) [============================================================] Object 1 of 1 Resolving links (4/6) [============================================================] Object 1 of 1 Loading headers and footers (5/6) [> ] 1% [=> ] 3% [===> ] 5% [===> ] 6% [====> ] 8% [======> ] 10% [=======> ] 12% " stdout: "" command: "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf" --lowquality --margin-bottom "30mm" --margin-top "40mm" --page-size "a4" --encoding "UTF-8" --enable-javascript --javascript-delay "13500" --enable-local-file-access --enable-smart-shrinking --no-stop-slow-scripts --footer-html "C:\Users\RAGINE1\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy64b90da61bd510.93606603.html" --header-html "C:\Users\RAGINE1\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy64b90da61bf1d8.66548341.html" "C:\Users\RAGINE1\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy64b90da61baf51.08168467.html" "C:\Users\RAGINE1\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy64b90da61bcec9.78969162.pdf".

**I tried the below:**

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('report.pdf.Report', $data=['Products'=>$Products])
           ->setOption('margin-top', '40mm')
           ->setOption('margin-bottom', '30mm')  
           ->setOption('enable-javascript', true)
           ->setOption('javascript-delay', 13500)
           ->setOption('enable-smart-shrinking', true)
           ->setOption('no-stop-slow-scripts', true)
           ->setOption('header-html', $headerHtml)
           ->setOption('footer-html', $footerHtml)
           ->setPaper('a4');
         
        return $pdf->inline();
```

**Also tried in snappy.php**

```
'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"',
        'timeout' => 3600,
        'options' => [
            'enable-local-file-access' => true,
            'encoding'      => 'UTF-8'
        ],
        'env'     => [],
    ],
```

Still, I can't able to find the solution.